# IllegalArgumentException w/accessing a mysql db via query

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to return the results of a query but am getting the following error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type [java.sql.ResultSet]

Here is my requestmapping:

```
    @RequestMapping(path="getAVGYTDStats.do", method = 
    RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getAvgYTDStats() throws SQLException {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    List<Double> stats; 
    stats = housedao.getAvgPriceYTDStats();
    System.out.println("stat after retrieval: " + "\n" + stats);
    mv.addObject("stats", stats);
    mv.setViewName("WEB-INF/views/stats.jsp");

    return mv;
```

And here is my DAO accessor:

```
    public List<Double> getAvgPriceYTDStats() throws SQLException {

    String sql = "select avg(h.closedPrice), avg(h.soldConcessions)                         
    from House h where h.closedDate>=\'2018-01-01\'";

    ResultSet avgSalesYTD = em.createQuery(sql,                 
    ResultSet.class).getSingleResult();

    if (avgSalesYTD.next()) {
    System.out.println(avgSalesYTD.getFloat(1));
    System.out.println(avgSalesYTD.getFloat(2));
    }

    List<Double> stats = new ArrayList<Double>(); 
    stats.add(avgSalesYTD.getDouble(1));
    stats.add(avgSalesYTD.getDouble(2));

    avgSalesYTD.close();

    return stats;
    }
```

I'm running in circles trying to get it to work. It compiles but executes with the above exception.

Any advice? Thank you!

EDIT: Okay, I've read the replies (THANK YOU!) and "think" I'm on a better track. Here's what I've done now:

```
    public List<Double> getAvgPriceYTDStats() throws SQLException {

    List<Double>stats  = 
            em.createQuery(
            "select avg(h.closedPrice), avg(h.soldConcessions) from                 
     House h where h.closedDate>=\'2018-01-01\'")
            .getResultList();

    return stats;
    }
```

I think what I'm doing here is calling the method / query from my RequestMapper, asking for a List of Doubles, then returning that list to the Controller and RequestMapper.

I'm then adding that object to my model and printing it out on my JSP.

Problem is no to String but I can't figure out how to convert it in a way that displays.

Comment: The query has two columns. How do want to to convert it to a single `List<Double>`?

Comment: maybe you need to use getResultList() rather than getSingleResult()

Comment: @Harpz, I'm getting the same result w/ getSingleResult();

Comment: @Mureinik -- can you elaborate? I "think" that when executing that query, I'm asking the database to give me back two doubles. But I get the same error when I ask for getResultList()

Comment: I tried this: same effect. What am I doing wrong?                                         
`code` public List<Double> getAvgPriceYTDStats() throws SQLException {
`code`  String sql = "select avg(h.closedPrice), avg(h.soldConcessions) `code`              from 
`code`               House h where h.closedDate>=\'2018-01-01\'";
`code`        List<Double> avgSalesYTD = em.createQuery(sql, 
 `code`       Double.class).getResultList(); 
  
`code` System.out.println("**************************");
`code`  System.out.println(avgSalesYTD);
`code`  return avgSalesYTD;
`code` }

Answer (score 0):

That `ResultSet.class` expression in your `createQuery` call is not how you use this API.  You put the expected type in that and then the `getSingleResult` method takes care of folding the 1 row you get back into an object.

But in this code you are the one doing the effort of reading out the data. So, don't use `getSingleResult`, just get a resultset as normal. I don't recognize the DB API you're using here (It's for example not clear what the type of the 'em' variable is), so you'd have to check the documentation for how to do this. It should be quite simple.

Comment: I'm trying to read through the documentation but I'm not quite tracking what you're saying. 

I "think" I'm asking for the query to give me two doubles. 
`code` List<Double> avgSalesYTD = em.createQuery(sql, code Double.class).getResultList();   

This produces the same result.